# Creating a users table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id int(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(30) NOT NULL
  );
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error starting at line 1 in command:
> `CREATE TABLE users ( user_id int(5) PRIMARY KEY, username varchar(25) NOT NULL, password varchar(30) NOT NULL )`

> Error at Command Line:2 Column:13
> Error report:
>
> `SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`
>
> `00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"`
>
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @rontornambe `ORA`- stands for Oracle

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376662/sql-error-ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis

Comment: I just want to point out, you shouldn't be storing a plain text password in the user table.  Hash it first using a good hashing algorithm with salt, like [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) and then store the hash/salt, not the actual password.  When validating, run the hash on the entered password and compare it to the stored value.

Answer (score 3):

don't try to put precision for integer type:

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(30) NOT NULL
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's related to your `int(5)` data type specification.  See [Oracle numerica data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209).

Try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(30) NOT NULL
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works, but note that the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is added at the end of the command

```
CREATE TABLE users( 
     user_id int NOT NULL,
     username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
     password varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score -1):

To create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id int(5) NOT NULL,
  username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
  );
```