# SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I don't know what is wrong with this syntax.

```
create table table3 (
id number,
id_table1 number,
id_table2 number,
area varchar2(130) not null,
status varchar2(20),
additional_info varchar2(100),
data date default sysdate,
responsable varchar2(60) not null,
constraint ck_status_contract check(status in('value1','value2','value3')),
constraint fk_id_table1 references table1 on delete set null,
constraint fk_id_table2 references table2 on delete set null,
constraint pk_id_contract primary key(id)
);
```

The result is:

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

I use OracleXE112_Win64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your FK you need to specify the columns affected on both ends

```
CONSTRAINT fk_column
FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
REFERENCES parent_table (column1,..)
```

Comment: the error, which is not that suggestive, distracted me from seeing that I forgot to specify the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

**You have missed to add foreign key references properly.**

To specify `foreign key` constraint, you should either use inline

```
CONSTRAINT [constraint_name] FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES [master_table_name]([master_column_name])
```

See more example from this tutorial: [What is foreign key?](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Foreign_key)

### Resource Link:

[SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376662/sql-error-ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis)